# Arithmetic Operator's Header File in C++

Tags: c++, header-files, dev-c++

what are the header files responsible for arithmetic operations like :
addition, subtraction,increment,decrement for particular compiler like DEVC++

thanks in advance:)

Comment: Those operators are built into the language like int and double. You can [overload them](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) for your own purposes, though.

Comment: Arithmetic is built into the language. No header files are needed to define, for example, addition

Comment: why don't you write a little program to test which are built in...then you should/could surmise the rest would need to be directives?  Just curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header files serve for declarations. Operations if they are not user-defined (that is not overloaded for user-defined types) by means of user functions are not declarations. So they do not require header files.